# sorting the tags and print id with coordinates

Tags: python, dictionary, tags

I need to sort out the data openstreetmap file with map. I need to find only ways which are closed (first nd coordinate is equal to last), and what's more only ways for tag with key=='building'. Then I need to print out its id and on the next string the vocabluary with list of tuples, containing the coordinates of nodes, which are included in this way. It can look like this:

```
28889642

[(55.5652795, 37.5695507), (55.5651145, 37.5702288), (55.5648475, 37.5700314), (55.5650147, 37.5693509), (55.5652795, 37.5695507)]



28911067

[(55.5683532, 37.5644676), (55.5682987, 37.5644271), (55.5679549, 37.5641683), (55.5679974, 37.5639919), (55.5683976, 37.5642929), (55.5686577, 37.5632112), (55.5687302, 37.5632692), (55.5687094, 37.5633574), (55.5687319, 37.5633741), (55.5686567, 37.5636906), (55.5686342, 37.5636738), (55.5685984, 37.5638247), (55.5686198, 37.5638406), (55.5684996, 37.5643462), (55.5684605, 37.5643171), (55.5684327, 37.5644347), (55.5683718, 37.5643896), (55.5683532, 37.5644676)]
```

My code allows me to find appropriate ways and print them, but it does not see the vocabulary with coordinates appropriate for this way.

The code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, urlretrieve
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import  urlopen, urlretrieve

response = urlopen(' https://stepik.org/media/attachments/lesson/266078/mapcity.osm')
xml = response.read().decode('utf8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'lxml')
dict = {}

for node in soup.find_all('node'):
    lat = node['lat']
    lon = node['lon']
    id = node['id']
    dict[id] = (lat, lon)

for way in soup.find_all('way'):
    if way.find_all('nd')[0]==way.find_all('nd')[-1]:
        for tag in way('tag'):
            if tag['k'] == 'building':
                print(way['id'])
            elif way['id'] in dict[id]:
                print(dict[id])
```

Comment: I improved the formatting of your post, and somebody else also did make some improvements already. Please see [Markdown Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to learn how to format the code correctly for your next question. PS: I know that the amount of whitespace/new lines is a personal preference and does not change the code, but an empty line between every line of code is very uncommon and I think most persons find it easier to read without so much blank lines, hence I removed many blank lines. I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with BS. I'll give you another example. The code logic is interlinked. I hope it can help you.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils, req
res = req.get('https://stepik.org/media/attachments/lesson/266078/mapcity.osm')
xml = res.read().decode('utf-8')
doc = SimplifiedDoc(xml)
dic = {}
for node in doc.nodes:
    lat = node['lat']
    lon = node['lon']
    id = node['id']
    dic[id] = (lat, lon)

for way in doc.selects('way'):
    nds = way.selects('nd>ref()') # Find all nd
    building = way.select('tag@k=building') # Judge whether there is a tag with k = building
    if nds[0]==nds[-1] and building:
        print(way['id'])
        print([dic[nd] for nd in nds if nd in dic])
```

Result:

```
28889642
[('55.5652795', '37.5695507'), ('55.5651145', '37.5702288'), ('55.5648475', '37.5700314'), ('55.5650147', '37.5693509'), ('55.5652795', '37.5695507')]
28911067
...
```

Comment: Maybe you know how to export the "lat" and "lon" values without parenthesis. I mean like this: [(55.5652795, 37.5695507), (55.5651145, 37.5702288)??

Comment: The question is solved, I have used function float to determine dictionary values